# Why object is not available on template when iron-router is returning that object

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a route controller for a page like as given below, which returns an object. But I am not able to find this object when the template is rendered, but when I print using console.log, the obecjt is being returned correctly to the template.

```
  MyPageController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'myPage',
    increment: 5,
    commentsLimit: function() {
        return parseInt(this.params.commentsLimit) || this.increment;
    },
    findOptions: function() {
        return {sort: this.sort, limit: this.commentsLimit()};
    },
    subscriptions: function() {
        this.myObjectSub = Meteor.subscribe('singleObject', this.params._id);
        this.commentsSub = Meteor.subscribe('comments', this.params._id, this.findOptions());
    },
    comments: function() {
        return Comments.find({myObjectId: this.params._id}, this.findOptions());
    },
    myObj: function() {
        return MyObects.findOne(this.params._id);
    },
    data: function() {
        var hasMore = this.comments().count() === this.commentsLimit();

        return {
            myObj: this.myObj(),
            comments: this.comments(),
            ready: this.myObjectSub.ready,
            nextPath: hasMore ? this.nextPath() : null
        };
    },
    sort: {submitted: -1, _id: -1},
    nextPath: function() {
        return Router.routes.myPage.path({_id:this.params._id, commentsLimit: this.commentsLimit() + this.increment});
    }
});
```

My route is defined as such:

```
Router.route('/myobjects/:_id/:commentsLimit?', {
name: 'myPage',
controller: MyPageController
});
```

I am not able to find out why MyObject is not being found by the MyPage template, where as the comments are available. When I check using console.log on RouteController, MyObj is returned correctly.

**EDIT:**
I can find myObj in the console when the page is loaded, so its that when the template is rendered, the myObj is still not available to the template.

So when I return data in this form, the myObj is found and loads fine.

```
data: function() {return MyObjects.findOne(this.params._id);}
```

But when I want to return more than one variables, I can find other variables like comments & nextPath but not myObj?? Why is this so?

```
return {
        myObj: this.myObj(),
        comments: this.comments(),
        ready: this.myObjectSub.ready,
        nextPath: hasMore ? this.nextPath() : null
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the obj might not be available when template loads, you can do the following to load all the object values reactively when the data is available:

```
Template.myPage.helpers({

    _id: function() {
        return this.myObj ? this.myObj._id : '';
    },
    title: function() {
        return this.myObj ? this.myObj.title : '';
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When the template is about to be shown in the browser, you start your subscriptions. The template will then be rendered directly (before the subscriptions are ready!), and at that time, the browser hasn't received the object yet. That's why `MyObects.findOne(this.params._id)` evaluates to null in your template, but to the object you expect when you later evaluate the equivalent `MyObects.findOne` call in the console (when the subscriptions are ready).

Comment: Yes I can find the object in the console. So how can I make sure that the template waits for the subscriptions to be ready? I thought in the data block, "ready"is doing that job, that is it only returns when the MyObj subscription is ready. But apparently that is not happening.

Comment: I also tried with putting the subscrption in waitOn, but its still not working